# How can I get month moment js in loop on the vue?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, momentjs, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a problem

Look at this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/YzzWyaR?editors=1010

If the script executed, the result of `console.log(date)`  is

[image]

Whereas from my script should the result

```
2019-10-01
2019-10-02
...
...
2019-10-31
```

why the results don't match?

if I choose next month, the results will also not match

Comment: Is it working fine now after adding below fix?

Answer (score 0):

Updated for loop initialisation for(var i = 1; i <= totalDay; i++) {
and let date = moment().month(val.split('-')[1]-1).date(i).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

Now it works as expected

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    date: '2019-10-15',
    id: 5
  }),
  methods: {
    pickerUpdate: async function(val, id) {
      let totalDay = moment(val, "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() 
      console.log(totalDay)
      for(var i = 1; i <= totalDay; i++) {
        let date = moment().month(val.split('-')[1]-1).date(i).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        console.log(date)
      }

    },
  },

})
```

codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/dyyXYgQ?editors=1010